# Linux process how to pass data from parent to child

Tags: linux, process, subprocess

Hello fellow programmers. I hope you can help me out.

How can I create a sub process in Linux, then print out the PID of parent and child processes and pass data from parent process to child process

Comment: In what language? And have you done any basic searching and research at all?

Comment: bash programming ,...basically i need just a way to pass data from parent process to child but without c code

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you look at shared memory.

Just to get you started, look at the man of :
`ipcmk`, `ipcrm`  and `ipcs`.